# How can I make a particular Textview item as bold and set its color

Tags: android, textview

I'm a newbie here. I'm asking   How can I make a Textview paticular item of bold and color like as a 23458 ? I want 4 and 8 digit as bold and in red color.

I have a search item say 29861 but only two  characters from it match with 32458 i.e. 1 and 8 so I want to bold these two item of Textview as bold and in red color and other characters should be normal.
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`Html`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html) class to generate a [`Spanned`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spanned.html), which can be used in the [`TextView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html).

```
TextView tv = ...;
Spanned text = Html.fromHtml("23<font color=\"red\"><b>4</b>5<b>8</b></font>");
tv.setText(text);
```

You can use many basic HTML attributes in [the `.fromHtml() method`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml(java.lang.String)), which are all listed in [this blog post](http://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html), courtesy of [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware).

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I want to use this for dynamic string. I have a web-service that return different result and when a user search for a string. so if the search string is available how to make those character bold dynamically.

Comment: Find them in the string and replace them by hand. Such as `str = str.replaceAll("0", "<b>0</b>");`. Then use `fromHtml(str)`.

Comment: I tried but str.replaceAll method replace all string with paticular string bold format.I want that only those character make a bold not replace by the search string.